# Froala editor v2 (new) inline destroy bug(?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, froala

Using the newest version of the froala editor (v2) doesn't seem to work when destroying an inline editor. 
It leaves this element in the editor element: `<i class="fa fa-code"></i>`. You can see this behaviour if you go to the inline example-site: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/v2.0/docs/examples/inline

And enter the following into the developer console: $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('destroy');

Does anyone know how to mend this? It also leaves the editors wrappers inside the editorcontainer and preserves editorclasses on it even though the documentation states that the destroy command will remove the editor in its entirety and  the element back to its pre-init state.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this JSFiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/froala/8yxLcg5k/

```
$(function() {
  $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor();
});

// Destroy action.
$('a#btn-destroy').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($('div#froala-editor').data('froala.editor')) {
    $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor('destroy');
  }
});

// Initialize action.
$('a#btn-init').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!$('div#froala-editor').data('froala.editor')) {
    $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor();
  }
});
```